# Setting up MongoDB shard locally:13080 code no unix socket support on windows

Tags: mongodb, sockets, unix, sharding

I'm running 3 mongoDB instances in my Windows machine which i would like to add for sharding.

> mongos --configdb "ReplicationSet/TRICONNODE139:27018,TRICONNODE139:27019,TRICONNODE139:27020" --port 27030

And getting error code `13080`. No unix socket support on windows
Any idea why this is coming and how to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest you to follow this tutorial and let us know results. https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/

Comment: @hemanth-kotipalli, could you pl share the solution if you had find one? We are facing the same issue Location13080 with MongoDB (mongos.exe) 3.4.9.